# Policy not found WSO2 Identity Server 5.3.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm trying to use WSO2 Identity Server 5.3.0 from source that is running properly.

I already configured Service Provider using SAML 2.0 on tenant and it is working properly. The option "Enable Authorization" is checked (Service Provider > Local & Outbound Authentication Configuration)

Now, I need to apply some access rules inside this tenant. Based on this, I'm creating a policy following this guide.
https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Configuring+Access+Control+Policy+for+a+Service+Provider

The policy created just grant or deny access based on user role.

But when I try to log in with the user we got some message: AUTHORIZATION FAILED, You are not authorized to login to this application.

I made many changes trying to achieve correct rules, but isn't working properly.

What can I do to make this work properly ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using a vanilla 5.3.0 dist? There is a [known issue](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-5580) with tenants, and it is fixed now in public branch and will be available for 5.4.0. The fix is also available as an update at [WUM](http://wso2.com/update) for IS 5.3.0.